# How to click buttons and get information from textbox in HTML with VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to webscrape https://appscvsmovil.supercias.gob.ec/portaldeinformacion/consulta_cia_menu.zul?expediente=87379&tipo=1

Where "expediente=87379" will always have a different number.
I'm trying to click on "Información General" and then, on the Pop-up window, I want to obtain the data right to "Tipo Compañía" which is a Text Box.
Then, I want to click in "Ubicación" tab and get the text from "Provincia" (the text box next to it) and finally click on "Contactos" and get some other fields.

I can open the web browser with `Navigate URL` command but I can't click or get text.

```vb
IE.Document.All.Item("id#").Click
IE.Document.All.Item("id#").Value
For Each MyHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") 'I also tried with div
    If MyHTML_Element.innerText = "Información General" Then MyHTML_Element.Click
Next
```

How do I tackle this webpage and get any information from it?

Comment: Google `vba web scraping`. Top of the list is a good video from wiseowl.com.

Comment: ^^ that is useful advice.Also, please try and limit to a single question. For example, you could [edit] the above into how do I click on  "Información General"? Then your code is fine. You have explained what is happening and you could state the expected outcome is the popup window. Your new question, posted separately after some more research could be about interacting with the pop-up.